# Facebook user's email address is...?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I've got an object that represents an email, and I'd like to send it as a message to a user on Facebook. What email address do I use as the destination for this email that will be received as a message on Facebook?

Answer (score 4):

You need to request a special pemission to send email to a facebook user.

Comment: They do this for security, so evil people can not spam or harass their members outside of facebook. Inside of facebook you can only send messages based on a user's privacy settings or something.

Answer (score 0):

In the "good news" department, Facebook has announced that soon you'll be able to email users with much less fuss:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Roadmap_Email

The timing hasn't been fully revealed yet, but supposedly, soon!